Apple review denied my submission over in-app purchases. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly
I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.
This is what their message was:

We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs which create a poor user experience. Specifically, the “Remove Ads” button was irresponsive. Please review the details and resources below and complete the next steps.

and then after:

Next Steps


When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.

Here's my entire in-app purchase class
import StoreKit
import SystemConfiguration

class InAppPurchaseManager: NSObject, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    
    static let shared = InAppPurchaseManager()
    
    var productRequest: SKProductsRequest?
    var products: [SKProduct]!
        
    override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    
    func unlockContent() {
        
        adsRemoved = true
        TitleScreen.shared.removeAdsButton.isHidden = true
        
        GameViewController.shared.bannerView.isHidden = true
        SavedSettings.shared.setAdsSettings()        
    }
    
    
    func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }
        
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
        let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
    
    
    func fetchProducts() {
        let productIdentifiers = Set(["remove_ads"])
        productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productRequest?.delegate = self
        productRequest?.start()
    }
    
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
        if let product = products.first {
            print("Fetched product: \(product.productIdentifier)")
        } else {
            print("Failed to fetch product")
        }
    }
    
    
    // These two methods below are to request a purchase/restore which are called from TitleScreen buttons "removeAdButton" and "restorePurchases"
    
    func requestPurchase() {
            if isInternetAvailable() {
                if let product = InAppPurchaseManager.shared.products.first(where: { $0.productIdentifier == "remove_ads" }) {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            try await InAppPurchaseManager.shared.purchase(product)
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to initiate purchase: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("No internet connection available")
                GameViewController.shared.showAlert(title: "Failure", message: "No internet connection available")
            }
        }
    
    
    func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
    
    
    func purchase(_ product: SKProduct) async throws {
        print("request called")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
    
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                
                print("Transaction Successful: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                
                unlockContent()
                verifyReceipt()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            case .failed:

                print("Transaction Failed: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            case .restored:
                
                print("Transaction Restored: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                
                unlockContent()
                verifyReceipt()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
            case .deferred:
                print("Transaction Deferred: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
                
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func refreshReceipt() {
        let receiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
        receiptRefreshRequest.start()
    }
    
    
    func verifyReceipt() {
        if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {
            do {
                let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

I call requestPurchase() from a SKSpriteNode button from a menu. When I test it from a sandbox environment, it prompts as it should and then properly does what it's supposed to. I'm guessing review doesn't get any prompt at all, but I also thought in-app purchases aren't supposed to work until it's approved and live? I also don't have a server to validate receipts, I was under the assumption that StoreKit 2 validates on-device.
If someone could help, I'd really appreciate it, I'm clueless at the moment.

“Remove Ads” button was irresponsive. check the button click event

In a sandbox test environment it works perfectly. The methods are being called and the purchase goes through, but outside of the test environment, app review is claiming it's not working. So I'm not sure what you mean or what I'm supposed to be looking for.

You should adopt storekit2 rather than this approach. It is much simpler to implement and therefore more reliable. Also I am concerned when I see things like TitleScreen.shared.removeAdsButton.isHidden and  GameViewController.shared.bannerView.isHidden. View controllers should not be singletons. The view controllers should fetch the purchase state in their viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear and mange their own subviews

Original StoreKit is deprecated in iOS 18

TitleScreen is an SKScene. removeAdsButton.isHidden just hides the SKSpriteNode (that acts as a button) after unlockContent is called. I didn't know view controllers shouldn't be singletons and I'm not entirely sure what you mean and how to fix my bad code here.

Also, from the resources I've seen and used, is this not a StoreKit 2 implementation?

It is not a StoreKit2 implementation. SKPaymentTransactionObserver and SKProduct are all original StoreKit classes.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api

You are ignoring every possible failure point. Something isn’t working as expected and you haven’t implemented any error handling. For every print that tells you in the console something is wrong you need something that will tell you/the user that something is wrong on the device.

The StoreKit config file from StoreKit 2 has about 19 tests. Trigger all of them and make sure something happens in each case. Also test a no internet scenario
